# Symfony 2.3 / FOS User Bundle duplicate definition of column

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

We use FOSUserBundle with Doctrine and need to change the mapping. The following approach worked fine wth Symfony 2.1.x:

1. Our User-Entity extends FOS\UserBundle\Model\User
2. Our mapping.orm.yml maps all fields used by the bundle

This is still the recommended approach (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/doctrine.md)

After upgrade to Symfony 2.3 this no longer works: the update "doctrine:schema:update --force" yields errors of the type

duplicate definition of column "x"

where x is any field already used by FOSUserBundle.

Does anybody know which changes cause this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure if this is relevant to what you are talking about, but it sounds like you need to be using [attribute overrides](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/override-field-association-mappings-in-subclasses.html)

For example if you wanted to make the `salt` property nullable your user entity `Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User` would need something like the following mapping

```
# user.orm.yml
Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity

    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }

    attributeOverride:
        salt:
            nullable: true

    # Other mapping definitions ...
```

Comment: As far as I see this means that we have in addition to extend our User class from UserBundle\Entity\User rather than from UserBundle\Model\User. We would like to avoid this because of possible side effects. But of course overriding is an option we have to keep in mind.

Comment: That is not the case, you can extend `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User`

Comment: We tested the approach and it seems that overriding does the job - at least in our situation: so far everything works as in the Symfony 2.1 context. But if you needed to change the type of a field used by FOSUserBundle  this no longer works, since attributeOverride cannot change the type.

Comment: There is a good reason for that, changing the type could break the functionality of the FOSUserBundle for example!